# Right-aligning text under images (without javascript)

Tags: html, css, alignment

I need some advice in creating a caption underneath an image, that is aligned to the right hand side. The image will change, so I can't use fixed value margins or anything like that - is this possible without javascript?

This is the basic layout, 'text-align: right' would work if I could somehow force the wrapper div to constrain to the image width, but currently it breaks past this. Any advice?

```
<style>
#section{height: 74%; padding-left:5%;}
    #photowrapper{position:relative;}
        #photo{height:100%; width:auto;}
        #detailsdiv{position:relative; text-align:right;}
</style>

<div id='section'>
    <div id='photowrapper'>       
        <img id='photo' src=../imgs/banan.jpg></img>
        <div id= 'detailsdiv'>banan</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Maybe an obvious question but it hasn't been asked that I can see.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle? And don't use id for css.

Comment: @BordiMan Could you explain why one shouldn't use `id`s in CSS?

Comment: Id's are good, just dont use them more than once per page per id or you get warnings that browsers ignore. =/

Comment: id's in css it's a bed rule and bad tone in css writing

Comment: @BordiMan Do you have source for that? Why is it bad?

Comment: Did you know about BEM or mCss technologies?

Comment: @BordiMan Those are methodologies, yes I am aware of them. That still doesn't explain why `id`s shouldn't be used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML/CSS Text under image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820850/html-css-text-under-image)

Comment: @JasonMArcher Its not the text under image that was the problem it was the right alignment...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `display: inline-block;` to the `#photowrapper` CSS

```
#photowrapper{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DyrS9/

Comment: Also give detailsDiv the css attribute word-wrap:break-word; to prevent words wider then the image from overflowing.

Comment: Thanks very much, out of interest why does this make it work?

Just to clarify I accepted this one because table-cell in my experience behaves weirdly more often, so I'm opting for this method.

Comment: @dnv This works because block level elements, which is what your `div` was to begin with, automatically take up the whole width. This is why your text was way too far right. Inline-block level elements are only as wide as their contents, meaning the borders of the `div` will be the same as the borders of the image.

Answer (score 3):

You can add `display:table-cell` (or `table`,`inline-block`) to `#photowrapper` :

```
#photowrapper{
    position:relative;
    display:table;
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JdzLv/2/)

Comment: Tableize all the things!